# Euler's approximation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, approximation

I have a project in MATLAB where I am to approximate the solution of a diff equation. To do that, I use `ode45` to get the "real solution" and compare it to Euler's approximation that I perform 3 times with halving the step every time. Here are my issues:

`ode45` doesn't seem to work on my computer. I get this message:

```
No help found for ode45.m.
```

When I type help `ode45` in the commando window and this

```
Error using ode45
Too many input arguments.

Error in Lab2 (line 51)
[f, u] = ode45(@myode, [pi/6 pi/2], 1);
```

So I switched to `ode23` and got a what I thought to be a quite good result. Problem is though that I noticed that the error in the last approximation becomes slightly smaller which shouldn't happens since the error gets only larger by every step... right?

To makes things worse, I tried to run my code with ode23 on the school computer and got different results (different solution curve). I tried then ode45 and got the same results. When I look at the curve and its values it is totally wrong since in my diff equation values should be decreasing instead of increasing like they do when I run them on the school computer.

I don't understand how the same code can produce two different results on different computers.

I don't understand either why ode45 is missing from  my computer. I have tried re-installing the new version and it is still the same.

I am totally confused...

Here is my code:

This is in a function file named myode

```
function dudf = myode(f,u)
k=1/20;
dudf = (-k*u.^3)/sin(f).^3;
end
```

This is the program

```
%Euler's method
f_init = pi/6;
f_final = pi/2;
u_init = 1;
k = 1/20;
n = 10; %number of steps
h(1) = (f_final-f_init)/n;
fh(1) = f_init;
uh(1) = u_init;

%calculate euler's approximation after every step
for i = 2:n+1
    fh(i) = fh(i-1)+h;
    uh(i) = uh(i-1)+h*(-k*uh(i-1)^3)/(sin(fh(i-1))^3);
end


%save vaules of ode45 at every step for first appr.
step0=pi/30;
fiend = pi/6 + step0;
odeu1 = [1];
step1 = [pi/6];
for i = 1:length(uh)-1
    [f, u] = ode23(@myode, [pi/6 fiend], 1);
    odeu1 = [odeu1 u(end)];
    step1 = [step1 fislut];
   fiend = fiend + step0;
end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: typing ``which ode45`` returns a path to the source of that function. For this computer it is ``/opt/matlab/R2011b/toolbox/matlab/funfun/ode45.m``. If the requested function is not found, it returns that as string as well. If ode45 is missing and you think that your Matlab-Version should have access to it (which you should, as it comes without toolbox dependencies as far as i know), this might be a case for the Mathworks support.

Comment: Please capitalise the first person ("I"); it will reflect better on you.

Comment: Thank you for your answers I will contact support :)